# When to use closures in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I came across a custom filter used in angularJS where we are returning a function with a logic for custom filter. Here I'm not able to understand when exactly i should be using closures. I tried to return a function with in a jquery call back function, but the control just doesn't go inside the function body, but the control goes inside the angularJS custom filter. Can someone help me understand the concept.

AngularJS Custom filter Code, where the control goes inside the anonymous function:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (curItem, txtSearch) {
        var results = [];
        if (txtSearch && curItem) {
            for (i = 0; i < curItem.length; i++) {
                // some logic for filter
            }
            return results;

            app.filter('myFilter', function () {
                return function (curItem, txtSearch) {
                    var results = [];
                    if (txtSearch && curItem) {
                        for (i = 0; i < curItem.length; i++) {
                            alert(curItem[i].name);
                        }
                        return results;
                    }
                }
            });}}});
```

Jquery function where i'm trying to pass the control with in the return anonymous function although i know like i will be able to do with in just the call back instead of using the closure.

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    return function () {
        alert('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is returning functions, but never executing those functions. You also appear to have repeated the same code block twice and missed some closing `}`

Comment: only time you ever would return inside a click handler would be to return `false` if you were trying to cancel the event. Returning a function doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @charlietfl I wanted to understand which are the scenarios where i should be using closures

Comment: well that's just a bit too broad of a question to be honest. Best suggestion would be don't add things that aren't needed until you encounter a problem

Comment: I'm afraid this is a very broad question so it will probably end up getting closed (there is no single "right" answer). To try and help you though, I recommend, reading this short book: "YDKJS: Scope and closures" https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should first understand what **closures** are before trying to use them. 
I recommend reading [You-Dont-Know-JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)  book on GitHub for getting clarity on this topic. It is very neatly and conceptually explained in [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch5.md) chapter.

After understanding what closures are and what are their advantages, you can yourself identify the situations where to apply it.

Hope it helps!